# Access Azure Subscription Resources using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I written power-shell script to get all resources under my subscription. Are there any azure RestAPI's available to achieve the same?

Comment: There's a REST API for that. PowerShell Cmdlets are a wrapper over this API only. Can you please share the PowerShell code so that I can point you to correct REST API page?

Comment: `Get-AzureRmResource` will get you the list of all items in your current subscription